# PHPThumb crop left side and right side of image

Tags: php, imagemagick, phpthumb

I'm trying to get an image and crop it then resize it to a thumbnail using [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/).  I want to crop the left side, right side, top and bottom in similar percentages. For example, crop 30% from left and 30% from right side; crop 40% from top bottomwards and 40% from bottom upwards How can I go about it. All I see in the manual is passing the SX value which I suppose only crops it mathematically from the bottom left(where x=0). I need to be able to crop from both sides towards the centre of the image. I hope you get what I mean.

I am using PHPThumb and not something custom since it has good JPEG compression when resizing, therefore the images have the clarity of the originals.

**IMPORTANT EDIT**: I have been notified that such a feature is not available in PHPThumb, anybody know of any such thumbnaik generator with the above cropping functions?

Comment: AFAIK PhpThumb does not have that option (yet). You can add a feature request on it's SourceForge page.

Comment: Do you know of any other thumbnail generator that can offer such capabilities?

Comment: Write your own. It is not hard. At least, try. And community will help you to improve your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Imagemagick -shave ( http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#shave )but would need to calculate the pixels from the percentages first.

Untested code:

```
$size = getimagesize($input);
$horizontal = round( ($size[0]x0.3), 0);
$vertical = round( $size[1]x0.4), 0);
$cmd = "$input -shave {$horizontal}x{$vertical}";  
exec("convert $cmd output.jpg");
```